# Moment timezone does not return correct time

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

So I am currently in the "America/Los_Angeles" timezone (PDT), but when I create a new moment object and pass it through moment tz to set its timezone to the very one I'm in ('America/Los_Angeles'), like so:

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
```

the wrong time is being returned. Specifically, it's 8 hours ahead. This happens for all other timezones I try as well.

Am I just fundamentally misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but is your computer's timezone set up correctly?

Comment: It sounds like its returning GMT. Are you sure you've included  momentjs.com/timezone?

Comment: Also, how do you determine the time? Is the output of `moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").toString()` also wrong?

Comment: @sabof I just double checked my machine's timezone, and all appears correct. If I just just run 'moment()' in the console, it returns as 'Mon Mar 31 2014 14:36:18 GMT-0700', which is correct. It's only when I run it through the '.tz()' setter that things get all weird.

Comment: I just ran it, and it returns the correct result.  Question: How are you looking at the output?  Did you try `.toString()` or `.format()` or one of the other output methods?  Or are you just looking at the `_d` internal property in the debug console?  (hint - don't do that)

Comment: @MattJohnson I checked both `toString()` and the `format()` output, and both of them are showing the same error. Very puzzling. Must be something strange with my setup here. I will keep digging...

Comment: See if you can reproduce it in a JSFiddle or similar and post a link.

Comment: @MattJohnson so this is showing up as '12:45' for me (it's 5:45pm here): http://jsfiddle.net/eCC2f/

Comment: How very odd.  I see it there too.  I will check deeper later tonight and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @MattJohnson! I wonder if it has something to do with a weird timezone-data export. I supposed I could start by trying to export a new one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I replaced your copy of moment-timezone.js with the one from [the web site](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), it returned the correct result.

Comment: Totally weird. I had grabbed my original copy earlier that day, but something must've been off. Regardless, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "[zone](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/)" you pass it an offset off `GMT`.

```
moment().zone(-8)
```

Comment: This is just another way of getting it done. The `.tz` works, you just have to include momentjs.com/timezone.

Comment: @JonathanM Yeah this way is more efficient if your only using a single timezone and don't need to make use of lots of time zones.

Comment: This only works if you know for a fact that `-8` is the correct offset for the moment in question.  `America/Los_Angeles` identifies the US Pacific time zone, which alternates between `-8` and `-7`.