# Can you freely convert dates between timezones?

Tags: javascript, date

If given a date in UTC (let's say) is it possible to convert to various time zones taking DST into account?

I'm interested if JS can do this natively, without me having a list of time zones and their offset.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moment.js: Format date in a specific timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone)

Comment: Moment.js is a library. I'm hoping this has a solution without having to include a 3rd party dependency.

Comment: Adding to @PWKad's comment: Timezones are a b****. The best idea is to use tested solutions like moment.js before building it yourself.

Comment: @Francisc You could also perform DOM Manipulation without jQuery but that doesn't mean you should : )

Comment: Yeah, but you first try without. Besides, this is what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

A date (in Javascript and in most other systems) is not "in" a particular timezone.  It measures the number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1, 1970 GMT, and "now".

Timezone only comes into play when you want to convert it to or from a human-readable format.

Comment: Yeah, so basically my question is given a Unix timestamp, how can you convert it to human readable format in various timezones.

Comment: Ah, sadly, the Javascript in the browser only knows two zones: its own and GMT (for you Brits, that's one zone).  For the general case, yeah, a library.

Comment: Haha, indeed. [extra chars]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getTimezoneOffset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) method.

Comment: That returns the offset of the current machine (if set properly). It doesn't provide information about the name of the timezone for example.