# parse time with timezone offset with moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am having a datetime with timezone offset in a span.

The span looks like this -

```
<span class="timestamp">2014-09-22 08:30:25 +0530</span>
```

Now with [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) I can convert it to local timezone of the browser using -

```
var $date = Date.parse($('.timestamp').html());
console.log($date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
```

which converts the original time(IST) to the browser's time zone.

How do I do the same thing using moment.js

Best Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone?rq=1

Comment: that answer is having the zone hardcoded - .zone(+0100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing much to do here. Its done by default -

```
console.log(  moment( $('.timestamp').html() ).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') );
```

I suppose this should be appended in the docs