# Moment Timezone, set default time zones

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I want to work in same timezone in my web application, I try to use de time zone default function
moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Madrid");
the dates conversions (json format) are bad, substact one day by default

Here is my plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/xsugHtDLLUfxugCJRwIZ?p=preview

Thanks

```
 var jsonDate = "/Date(118101600000)/"; // DD/MM/YY = 29/09/1973 

 alert(moment(jsonDate).format("DD/MM/YY")); // conversion ok

 moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Madrid");

 alert(moment(jsonDate).tz('Europe/Madrid').format("DD/MM/YY")); // substract one day by default 28/09/1973
 alert(moment(jsonDate).format("DD/MM/YY"));                     // substract one day by default 28/09/1973
```

Comment: I've changed the way that work with dates to avoid client conversions. Now I return the date in ISO format from the server.

Answer (score 1):

@kaken

Can u check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone.)

I followed that link to solve timezone issue.

**ex: moment(jsonDate).zone("+03:00");  // moment can able to parse JsonDate**

To work with named **timezones**, include Moment Timezone as well and use .tz()

```
// determines the correct offset for America/Phoenix at the given moment

moment(1369266934311).tz('America/Phoenix').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')

// always "2013-05-22 16:55"
```