# Convert hour to date time without adding +1

Tags: javascript, mongodb, momentjs

Hi im using moment js to convert this string `20:00` I tried:

```
var a = moment("20:00", "HH:mm")
console.log(a.format()) // 2016-09-08T20:00:00+01:00
```

the problem when I store in mongodb it become

```
2016-09-10T19:00:00.000Z
```

I want to store `2016-09-10T20:00:00.000Z`

anyway can explain why please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js: Format date in a specific timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone)

Comment: It looks like moment is trying to format the time for your time zone.  Are you in the UTC +1 time zone?

Comment: You need to format it with a specific timezone

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen I prefer to not use timezone thing ty

Comment: @Doe I don't think this is a matter of preference

Comment: @evolutionxbox the app that im builed there is nothing related to timezones i just want to convert time....

Comment: It's not possible to "not use timezones".  Javascript-generated Dates will be relative to the user's local time; you have to convert to UTC before storing (which is what mongo is doing for you.)

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you want to store `2016-09-10T20:00:00.000Z` what you are saying is that you want to assume that your date and time is UTC.

To assume that the date you are parsing is a UTC value, use `moment.utc`

```
var a = moment.utc("20:00", "HH:mm")
console.log(a.format()) // 2016-09-08T20:00:00Z
```

Note that when you parse a time without a date, moment assumes the current date. This may not be the behavior that you want.

I'm also not sure if you want a UTC date (which is what you are saying), or a local date without an offset indicator. If you want a local date without an offset indicator, simply use a format without an offset:

```
moment.utc("20:00", "HH:mm").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS')
"2016-09-08T20:00:00.000"
```

If you are dealing with local dates that do not have a time zone association, I recommend using `moment.utc` to parse, as this will ensure that the time does not get shifted to account for DST in the current time zone.

For more information about how to parse dates into the time zone or offset that you would like in moment, see [my blog post on the subject](https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/).

Answer (score 0):

This it how it should look:

```js
var a = moment("20:00", "HH:mm")
console.log(a.utcOffset('+0000').format())
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Doe, the problem is that you are using timezones when you create the date.

MomentJS uses your current timezone automatically.

Mongo however saves the time as it would be in another timezone.

Therefore, if you want the two strings to format the same way, you need to set the timezone.

Comment: Please check my edit. As you've got the right answer, but you forgot the OP wants `20:00` in UTC, not `20:00+01:00` which is `19:00` UTC.