# AngularJS UI DatePicker - Moment Timezone

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, momentjs

I'm using AngularJS Bootstrap UI Datepicker with moment and **moment-timezone**. I set an inital date based on given timezone. So Datepicker works well if I set Date object as a ng-model:

```
$scope.dt = new Date() //works
```

but if I want to get current time in given timezone nothing shows up in datepicker (here I'm sending string):

```
$scope.dt = moment(new Date()).tz("Pacific/Auckland").format(); //not working
```

How can I fix this. Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZtGdd43Y7XOuv72nj9IC?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js: Format date in a specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone)

Comment: It's not dublicate, here I now how to get date for specific timezone, but I can't show that date inside datepicker

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/nvjP4T6foMl2J2QpJZPp?p=preview something like this?

Comment: @G_S great works,  didn't know that was a problem in format method...thanks

Comment: Happy that it worked