# moment.js timezone get milliseconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I'm trying to get number of days passed. I'm storing epoch (milliseconds) for date.
I'm reading startDate from database (date value of first record) in milliseconds and I want to find current epoch in specified timezone.

I tried this:

```
var startDate = rows[0]['MIN_DATE'];
var endDate = moment().tz("America/New_York");
```

Then to calculate difference, I used:

```
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var daysCount = Math.ceil((endDate - startDate) / (oneDay));
```

The value of startDate is:

```
1522821600000 which is: Wednesday, April 4, 2018 2:00:00 AM GMT-04:00 DST
```

The value of endDate is:

```
Moment_d: Wed Apr 04 2018 22:24:45 GMT-0400 (EDT)_isAMomentObject: true_isUTC: true_isValid: true_locale: Locale_offset: -240_pf: Object_z: Zone__proto__: Object
```

The value of daysCount is 2, how?
How can I get milliseconds instead of object from:

```
moment().tz("America/New_York");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with following statement:

```
var endDate = moment().tz("America/New_York").valueOf();
```

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, use .valueOf() to get the value of moment.tz("America/New_York")

```
var endDate = moment.tz("America/New_York").valueOf()
```

I'm having difficulty understanding your question, but I believe you're trying to get the difference between the days considering the correct timezone. The following gives an accurate result using .diff() (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
var timeZone = "America/New_York"
var startDate = 1522821600000
var momentStartDate = moment.tz(startDate,timeZone)
var momentEndDate = moment.tz(timeZone)

alert(momentEndDate.diff(momentStartDate, 'days') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [fromNow()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) function. It is very straight-forward.

Do like this :

`moment(date).fromNow();`

It will give you number of days passed if date is past as well as number of days to go if date is future.

Below are is example:

```js
var date = 1522821600000; // your date

console.log(moment(date).fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Ashutosh for that look this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone