# momentJS format is reflecting wrong time

Tags: momentjs

Here is the date/time string I am passing into MomentJS

```
let value = '2018-07-21T17:09:51.000Z'
```

This should be 07/21/2018 @ 5:09:51 PM

```
moment(value).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
```

Moment returns: Saturday, July 21st 2018, 10:09:51 am

Why is it showing 10:09:51 am and not 5:09:51 PM ?

Thanks

Comment: Set the correct timezone, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer... as @jshamble indicated... make sure you are using the timzone method .utc()

Solution to my question in the example:

```
moment(value).utc().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")
```