# Convert unix timestamp to correct timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am in Timezone `A` and would like to print the current time in Timezone B. For Timezone `B`, I have its `utc_offset_b`, which is a value in seconds.

How can I do this using `momentjs`?

Is this correct? (i'm running it in Timezone `A`)

`moment().utc().add(utc_offset, "second").format('MMM Do, h:mm:ss a')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js: Format date in a specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

As long as `utc_offset` is the difference between the 2 offsets, this more or less does what you want.

It's important to note though that offsets are not timezones. A real timezone is usually express via a string like `Europe/Amsterdam` or `America/Toronto`.

If your model can use those timezone strings, this is *much* better. These timezones (which are supported by moment and many other systems) take in account things such as policy changes and daylight savings time.