# moment js doesn't return the correct date given week+year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using this code:

```
var year = 2018;
var week = 1;
var currentDate = moment().day("Sunday").year(year).week(week).toDate().format("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

currentDate result is 06/01/2018 (Saturday) instead of **07**/01/2018 (Sunday).

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Thanks,
Yael

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/moment-js-format-date-in-a-specific-timezone You need to set `timeZome` default UTC

Comment: [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) is a moment function, you can't use it on JS Date object. Removing `toDate()` you will get `Sa/01/yyyy` (because moment tokens are case sensitive) and not  `06/01/2018` as you stated in the question. please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `toDay` instead of `toDate`.  And don't forget to check time zone too.

Comment: There is no `toDay` function in momentjs.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the order and now it works well for the given example:

> var currentDate =
>   moment().year(year).week(week).day("Sunday").toDate();