# convert timezone pytz string to offset in python/django

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-timezone

I am using django/python

How do I convert pytz timezone string such as 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' to offset information ('+0800' or '80').

I am not able to find the exact function here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/

I would like to use it in moment.js like this:
[Format date in a specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/format-date-in-a-specific-timezone)

so the question is:
'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur' --> convert to ---> '+0800'

Comment: The problem is that a timezone is not just an offset. It comes with a set of rules like daylight saving time, the dates when to move between DST, etc. and a history of changes in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timezone is not an offset. It is a set of rules how to calculate the offset for a given datetime. This means the current rules for example about *daylight saving time (DST)*, and the historical ones where (small) changes have been made to the calendar.

You can determine the offset of the *current* datetime (or some other datetime) with:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> pytz.timezone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur').localize(datetime.utcnow()).strftime('%z')
'+0800'
```

For example for Brussels time, two different timestamps can give two different offsets:

```
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Brussels')
>>> tz.localize(datetime.utcnow()).strftime('%z')
'+0100'
>>> tz.localize(datetime(2020,5,1)).strftime('%z')
'+0200'
```

or for example *Pyongyang* changed the timezone on May 4th, 2018:

```
>>> pytz.timezone('Asia/Pyongyang').localize(datetime(2018,5,4)).strftime('%z')
'+0830'
>>> pytz.timezone('Asia/Pyongyang').localize(datetime(2018,5,5)).strftime('%z')
'+0900'
```

You thus can not simply map a timezone on an offset.