# How to have moment(time).format() return in the same timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to use .format() to convert the inputted time into 'ddd, MMM DD, hh:mma' format, but it returns it in the wrong timezone compared to the original intended timezone (America_NewYork).

```
const someday = moment('2023-01-27T12:21:08.088Z').format('ddd, MMM DD, hh:mma');
```

```js
const out = document.getElementById('output');
const someday = moment('2023-01-27T12:21:08.088Z').format('ddd, MMM DD, hh:mma');
out.innerText = someday;
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<p>Expected outcome: Fri, Jan 27, 12:21pm </p>
<p>Actual outcome: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date in a specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347589/format-date-in-a-specific-timezone)

Comment: you need to use moment time zone, then you can do something like this moment.tz(yourDate, timeZone).format('ddd, MMM DD, hh:mma');

Comment: The expected outcome is the utc datetime.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is get the UTC time and then use the local() method to convert that UTC date-time to your local time. Here is a sample code.

Just doing moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'), will give you the UTC time. You can also set UTC offset like moment(testDateUtc).utcOffset(10 * 60); //set timezone offset in minutes.

```js
const local = moment(moment.utc()).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
console.log(local);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```